# pgf inside macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

I'm trying to create a macro that conditionnaly print whatever it's given as argument. However, when such argument is a tikzpicture with a function definition, I get

```
Paragraph ended before pgfmath@local@@functions was complete
```

amongst other missing \endgroup's (and worse if I try to use that function). I had the same problem with inline foreach's, but I solved that by properly delimiting the foreach block with {}'s.

Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%compatibility babel & pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
#1
}

\begin{document}
\mymacro{%If I remove this macro, no errors.
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={myfun(\x)=\x;}]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,/pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    samples=50
]
    \addplot [thick, smooth, domain=-3:3] {myfun(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix this kind of problem ?

EDIT : still interested in a 'clean' fix for this (as this looks like a babel/pgf bug I might encounter again), but I went a different route in the end so no need for dirty stuff. Added plot in the MWE as it raises errors as well.

Comment: I don't have any problems with your code. What's the TikZ version you are using?

Comment: @percusse : 3.0.0 according to \pgfversion

Comment: Then there must be something else happening as I have the same setup.

Comment: What happens if you comment out all references to babel?

Comment: @LoopSpace : removing babel and the corresponding usetikzlib makes it work. But then I don't get babel for the rest :(

Comment: The problem is with the semi-colon in the `define function`.  Because you are using Babel, at the start of the document (but crucially not before), `;` is made active.  So the `;` in the `define function` bit is an active semi-colon.  However, the code executed by `define function` is expecting `;` with catcode of `other` so it panics.  The solution depends on what you're doing in the rest of the document.  You can switch `;` back to `12` using `\shorthandoff{;}` before the `\mymacro` call but then it is disabled inside the `\mymacro` call (and you need to switch it back on after).

Comment: Or you could redefine `declare function` to take an active semi-colon.  Or you could be even more sophisticated and have it try to detect the catcode of `;` at invocation time and behave according.  Which is the right solution depends on how you are using semi-colons in the rest of the document.

Comment: @LoopSpace : I'm using semi-colons as punctuation, or in mathmode to separate coordinates (french style). I have no idea how to do what you are proposing though :) In the end I ended up giving up on the macro and going in a different direction (python). But this probably should be adressed by \usetikzlibrary{babel}, should I report it somewhere ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you search here for `babel` and `tikz` you will find quite a lot of information about the issues caused when these packages are used together.  Quite a lot of work has been put into making them work nicely together, culminating in the `babel` tikz library.

The way that the `babel` tikz library works is to temporarily suspend babel's shortcuts inside the tikzpicture.  This ensures that all the "special" characters revert to their usual meaning and so the various mechanisms inside tikz and pgf don't get confused.  It does this by invoking a particular command when the tikzpicture environment is started.  The key here is that that command is invoked **before** any of the rest of the environment is parsed.

The problem with what you're doing is that by putting the tikzpicture inside a macro parameter, you're forcing TeX to read the entire code before examining it.  So when the tikzpicture is started and the magic invoked, the contents of the tikzpicture is already frozen and the magic has no effect[1].

Probably the cheapest way around is to make sure that your command freeze tikzpicture too early, or at least to invoke the magic command yourself before the tikzpicture is read.  Here's one way to do that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254955/86}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%compatibility babel & pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\newcommand{\mymacro}{%
  \begingroup
  \shorthandoff{;}
  \myrealmacro
}

\newcommand{\myrealmacro}[1]{%
  #1
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}

\mymacro{%If I remove this macro, no errors.
  \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={myfun(\x)=\x;}]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,/pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    enlargelimits=upper,
    samples=50
]
    \addplot [thick, smooth, domain=-3:3] {myfun(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[1] It's a well-known phenomenon that magic doesn't affect things that are frozen.

Comment: I consider microwave to be indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: thanks, this appears to be working just fine, and it's a pretty easy (global) fix in case I need this again. (I added babel to the tags as well)

Comment: I'm inclined to think it's a specific problem of `declare function`, because semicolons don't give problems in other parts even if the shorthand is not switched off, when the `tikzpicture` is absorbed as argument to a macro.

Comment: @egreg The TikZ parser goes to quite *extreme* lengths to avoid issues with changing catcodes to make it "just work".  Whoever wrote the `declare function` part didn't go to the same lengths.  I don't think that's really a problem with `declare function`, I think rather whoever wrote the TikZ code is to be congratulated for going to such great lengths to avoid the issue.  (A particularly neat trick is that an active `;` is defined to expand to a non-active `;` and then arguments are expanded in an `\edef` before the parser sees it.).

Comment: @egreg A little more experimenting shows that `pgfplots` suffers from the same issues.  Freezing semi-colons as active disrupts the `\addplot` parser.  So I'm inclined to say that "catcodes are tricksy" and that delimited macros are a nightmare.  Which is a shame as they can be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a specific problem with `declare function`, because

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%compatibility babel & pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

works without problems. Your issue doesn't depend on `\mymacro`, as it can be reproduced replacing it with `\mbox`.

Ugly workaround:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}%compatibility babel & pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{%
  #1%
}

\begin{document}

\mymacro{%
  \begingroup\let\begin\relax\let\x\relax\edef\x{\endgroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={myfun(\x)=\x\string;}]}\x
  \draw (1,1) -- (2,2);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yeah I have a lot of tikzpictures (tree, function plotting without declare function) that work just fine. Do I have to relax all variables like this ? I have three variables fonctions for some probability distributions.

Comment: this workaround doesn't seem to be working for me anyway.

Comment: @imj Maybe with a more detailed example…

Comment: it fails when I try plotting the function afterwards.

Comment: @imj No example, no possibility of getting more help, sorry.

Comment: gimme 5sec, I just updated the initial MWE